# LayoutInflator return null object reference on same syntax why?

Tags: android

I am accessing a layout from a class which extends activity when I use `LayoutInflator` in that class it returns null object reference but while when I use the same method in my Main Activity it works fine please somebody help me why this happens with me?

```
public class MenipulateCard extends Activity{
public LinearLayout myCard(
LayoutInflater myInflator = 
 (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        CardView view =  (CardView) myInflator.inflate(R.layout.user_layout,null);
        LinearLayout ml = new LinearLayout(this);
        ml.addView(view);
        return ml;
    }
```

it returns null object reference:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
```

but when I use the same method in the main activity I can get LinearLayout. Please help me, buddies

Comment: have you tried context.getSystemServic() instead of getApplicationContext().getSystemService?

Comment: android studio does not pop up any context.getApplicationContext for that pops only getBaseContext and getApplicationContext

Comment: I mean this.getSystemService()

Comment: Try simply: getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: `                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mudassir_ktk1.assignment/com.example.mudassir_ktk1.assignment.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
`    on calling getSystemService only

Comment: You cannot call `getApplicationContext()` or `getSystemServices()` before the `Activity` is properly initialized by the system; basically, not until `onCreate()` runs. Since you've not provided a [mcve], we cannot tell you with certainly what exactly to change. The code you've posted won't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method instead, but make sure your context is not `null`

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(yourContext).inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot);
```